# Filter Backbone Collection without removing models

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on a Backbone application to display songs pulled from Soundcloud. 
I have the search bar working as a filter for the collection of songs.

Results is the list of songs

```
var matched = results.filter(function(model) { 
    return model.attributes.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
});
results.reset(matched);
```

This works fine, and the songs disappear as I type. 
But I'm trying to find of way to add them back to the collection once they meet the search string again.

At this point, when I go back to an empty search string, the only thing showing are the results that were reached with the search.

================== EDIT ==================

This is what I ended up doing

```
    $("#query").on('focus', function(){

    var history = results.clone();

    $(this).on('keyup', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var matched = history.filter(function(model) { 
            return model.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
        });
        results.reset(matched)

    });
```

Comment: What exactly is does reset do here?

Comment: Also it is not a good idea user `attributes` property to get the data..   return `model.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1`

Comment: Is there anywhere that goes over getting attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filtering `results` put the result of filter in another array ('matched').

Keep a copy of the original collection contents (the models).

The view should only render the elements of the model that are matched. Alternatively, this logic can happen completely at the view level since there is no actual model logic involved.